# TikZ forest ignores tikzsetnextfilename

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest, tikz-external

I have the next structure

### Main.tex

```tex
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Draws & diagrams

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows.meta, shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{external}

% Compile with --shell-escape
\usepackage[edges, external]{forest}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=externalization/]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\NewDocumentCommand{\inputdiagram}{m}{
    \tikzsetnextfilename{#1}
    \input{diagrams/#1.tex}
}

\begin{document}
    \inputdiagram{FirstDiagram}
\end{document}
```

### FirstDiagram.tex

```tex
\begin{forest}
    forked edges,
    for tree = {
        anchor = center,
        rectangle,
        if = {level == 0}{
            l sep = 10mm,
            outer color= lilac,
            text width = 0.25\linewidth,
            for tree = {
                for children = {
                    grow'=0,
                    folder
                }
            }
        }{},
    },
    [Nivel 0
        [Nivel 1.1
            [Nivel 2.1.1]
            [Nivel 2.1.2]
            [Nivel 2.1.3]
        ]
        [Nivel 1.2
            [Nivel 2.2.1]
            [Nivel 2.2.2]
        ]
        [Nivel 1.3
            [Nivel 2.3.1]
            [Nivel 2.3.2]
        ]
        [Nivel 1.4
            [Nivel 2.4.1]
            [Nivel 2.4.2]
            [Nivel 2.4.3]
        ]
    ]
\end{forest}
```

I'm creating a simple diagram, but when I try to externalize, forest just ignores `\tikzsetnextfilename` and creates `Main-forest-1`, `Main-forest-2`, etc.

For Ti*k*Z it works pretty well, creating the files with the indicated name. Is it possible to set a name to a forest externalization?

Comment: Forest plays fast and loose with TikZ externalization, so if I remember correctly, `\tikzsetnextfilename` indeed does not work. Related advertisement: at the moment, I'm finalizing a new externalization package, Memoize. The proof-of-concept version is available at GitHub, https://github.com/sasozivanovic/memoize, and the first official version should be published to CTAN beginning of autumn.

Comment: @SašoŽivanović thanks :)

Comment: @SašoŽivanović Wondering if you got any further with this. The ability to externalise `prooftrees` tableaux would be awesome. (Also, externalisation fails for many pictures in my experience, including most of my `forest` trees.)